# Complex Numbers Midpoint of Roots of Unity

Tags: complex-numbers, polar-coordinates, roots-of-unity

A = $\sqrt{2}e^{i(\frac{7\pi}{12})}$

B = $\sqrt{2}e^{i(\frac{11\pi}{12})}$

Express the midpoint M of AB in the form $a + bi$

(a,b in simplified surd form)

I know M = (A+B)/2 but I cant find A+B in a simple enough form.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'd convert $A$ and $B$ to cartesian coordinates:

$A = \sqrt{2}(\cos(7\pi/12)+i \sin(7\pi/12))$

$B=  \sqrt{2}(\cos(11\pi/12)+i \sin(11\pi/12))$

Then you can easily compute

$M=(A+B)/2 = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} (\cos(7\pi/12)+\cos(11\pi/12)+i\left[\sin(7\pi/12)+\sin(11\pi/12)\right])$

Comment: I've done that already, my problem is in getting from here to the form a +bi

Comment: The last line is exactly in your desired form.

Comment: as stated in the question, a,b need to be expressed in simplified surd form. sin and cos are not surds

Comment: Then please explain what *surd* means. If you want to avoid $\sin$ and $\cos$ I recommend using one of the many trigonometric identities. If you draw your numbers you wil see that $M$ has an argument of $9\pi/12$ or $3\pi/4$ and finding the sine or cosine of that angle is not difficult.

Comment: surds are square roots e.g $\sqrt{3}$

Comment: the answer is meant to be; $.-\sqrt{3}/2 + i\sqrt{3}/2$

Comment: Good. I am sure you'll find something here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities

Comment: Why the downvotes?